# Is there a faster way to update numpy array using two other arrays one containing index1,index2 and other containing values?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, list-comprehension

I can change data structures into something else probably a dictionary if that helps but I want to make this updation faster

```
a=np.ones([5,5])
print(a)
b= np.array([[1,1], [2,2], [4,4]])
print(b)
c=[10,10,10]
for i in range(len(b)):
    [ind, ind2]=b[i]
    a[ind, ind2]= c[i]
print(a)
```

Comment: This should work: `ro, co = zip(*b); a[ro, co] = c`

Comment: a[tuple(zip(*b))] = c

Comment: `a[b[:,0], b[:,1]] = c`

Comment: `a[tuple(b.T)] = c`

Comment: Thanks all! All these methods work.
I did understand hpaulj matlab inspired method, I will study some tutorials about zip and "*"